# adding adorners to legacy textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, interop, legacy

Whats the best way to add an adornment layer to legacy controls, or in other words you know jetbrains refactoring tools, how do they draw the squiggly lines under incorrect text? 
Also on another note can one draw said adorments on controls not under the direct reference of the application, ie using a handle? If you have insights, or just theories, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some resources

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302340(loband).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/DoubleBuffering.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775487(VS.85).aspx (Rich Textbox)